# Default primary key setting increases value by two

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, primary-key

I have just created a database in Visual Studio using a C# Forms application.

I have a number of columns, column A being the primary key.

I have just entered data into the row, and have noticed that the primary key value increases by two (`1,3,5,7,9....` etc).

Is there a way to alter it to ascend in a regular way (`1,2,3,4,5,6,....?`)

[image]

Comment: Which database are you using ? and can you show the create table statement in your question

Comment: Show us the script that you used to create the table

Comment: I added the table by clicking on the database in the server explorer.

Comment: Remember: the "identity PK" will be "taken" in a transaction, even if the TX is rolled-back. That is, there is no guarantee that it is ever strictly by 1 (or whatever the increment is). In any case, try to create two records *within the same serializable TX* - are they sequential then? Also, other things such as triggers could be interfering.

Answer (score 5):

If you use MS SQL Server, open your table in SQL Management studio or In Visual Studio and set Primary Key's `Identity Increment` = 1

[image]

Comment: It is interesting.. Do you enter data manually or your application does?

Comment: Manually. I recently deleted the table, created a new one, and now it won't generate the primary key figures automatically at all, I have to do it myself.

Comment: @KiraBorke Sounds like there is *no* identity column specified at all then - either that or [`SET IDENTITY_INSERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259221%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) has been changed.